# Issue with adding to array while passing data to another view

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm having a struct like so..

```
    struct Product {
        let name : String
        let id : String

    }
 }
```

I also have a separate array of images called `arrayOfURLImages` Now I'm having a `collectionview` and each cell of the `collectionview` has an image from the `arrayOfURLImages` and 2 labels showing the `id` and `rate`. And when I click on an item of the `collectionview`, I load a tableviewcell which has this image of the `collectionview` on it and also the `id` and `name`.

On clicking on the collectionview this is how I am passing the `image` and the `name` & `id`…

```
func SellBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

 let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPath(for: ((sender.superview?.superview) as! RecipeCollectionViewCell))

 self.photoThumbnail = self.arrayOfURLImages[(indexPath?.row)!]

 let myVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: “mydentifier") as! myViewController
 myVC.myImage = self.photoThumbnail

let productObject = productData1[(indexPath?.row)!]

 myVC.prodName = productObject.name <— ‘name’ from struct 
 myVC.prodId = productObject.id <— ‘id’ from struct 

 navigationController?.pushViewController(myVC, animated: true)
 }
```

Now my issue is I want to add the tableviewcells thus loaded into an array. Also in the viewcontroller from where the tableviewcell is loaded, this is how I am assigning the data in the `cellForRowAt`…

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: sellTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sellProductIdentifier") as! sellTableViewCell

cell.IdLabel.text = prodId
cell.nameLabel.text = prodName

  return cell
}
```

Currently, in the `numberOfRowsInSection`, I’m just giving return 1 and so just one cell is displayed but I want to add my cell to an array and get the `noOfItems` as the count of that array…

Hope someone can help…:)

**EDIT:**

What I actually want to achieve is, when I click on one collection view item, one tableviewcell is shown and when I go back and click on the second collection view item, 2 tableviewcells should be shown each having the the data from the first and second collectionview cell respectively.

Comment: Don't clearly understand your problem. You want to make an array of cells and display it right ?

Comment: Yes, @Arrabidas92..but since structs is used I'm a bit confused...

Comment: you need to pass more than just one struct to the view controller

Comment: But how thats done...that I'm not sure...@Lu_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to pass the `productData1` to the next ViewController

Simply make the instance member in `myViewController`

```
var arrProduct: [Product]?
```

and pass it just like this:

```
myVC.arrProduct = productData1
```

And return the count of your array `arrProduct.count` in `numberOfRowsInSection`.

and use it in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
let product = arrProduct[indexPath.row]
cell.IdLabel.text = product.id
cell.nameLabel.text = product.name
```

**Edit:**

```
    var selectedItems: [Product]?
    func SellBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

     let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPath(for: ((sender.superview?.superview) as! RecipeCollectionViewCell))

     self.photoThumbnail = self.arrayOfURLImages[(indexPath?.row)!]

     let myVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: “mydentifier") as! myViewController
     myVC.myImage = self.photoThumbnail

    let productObject = productData1[(indexPath?.row)!]
    if selectedItems == nil {
       selectedItems = [Product(name:productObject.name, id:productObject.id)]
    }else {
        selectedItems.append(productObject)
    }
     myVC.arrProduct = selectedItems

     navigationController?.pushViewController(myVC, animated: true)
     }
```

**Note: Class name should start with capital letter and instance member with small letter, Also the name should be descriptive.**

Comment: But @Salman Ghumsani, I can't do like so..var arrProduct: [Product]? since the struct 'Product' is in the viewcontroller where I have set up the collectionview. It's not defined in myViewController. So it throws an error of undeclared type 'Product'

Comment: Don't worry Declare it file level.

Comment: Declare the structure top of the file means outside the class scop.

Comment: the struct issue worked as you suggested, @Salman Ghumsani. But the main issue sort of persists. I have about 10 collection view items and when I click on the button of one item, the tableview to which data is passed is loaded with cells showing all the data from the collection view(i.e. 10 cells are loaded). While actually . when I click on the button at the 1st collecn view item, just that item should be added to the array and shown in the tableview and when I return back and click on the 2nd collecn view item, both the 1st & 2nd collcn view items should be added to the array...

Comment: Ohhk that is a different scenario.

Comment: Now you have to prepare a separate array then pass it I am updating my answer!

Comment: Tried what you suggested, @Salman Ghumsani and the cells are properly getting added to the array. But the image that is passed is not proper...Actually there is another struct for images and that too has to be passed it seems...Doing self.photoThumbnail = self.arrayForURLImages[(indexPath?.row)!] doesn't work...

Comment: Have also given the complete structure of structs in the question for reference(in the initial part of the question)

Comment: No, You can only ask what's the problem because now it is a different problem.
You have to show both structures.

Comment: .@Salman GhumsaniThe issue with passing the image still seems to persist. Did try a lot...but something sure is missing...since you are familiar with the issue as a whole, maybe you can have a clear idea...would you mind having a look at it...? this is the link...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46767967/issue-with-adding-the-collection-view-image-to-an-array-while-passing-data-to-an?noredirect=1#comment80482071_46767967