# Issue with adding the collection view image to an array while passing data to another view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm having a struct like so...

```
struct ProductImage {
   let id : String
   let url : URL
   let isDefault : Bool
}

struct Product {
    let name : String
    let id : String
    var images = [ProductImage]()
    var theRate : String
    var quantity: String
    var sku: String
    var prdCateg: String
    var prodDescr: String

    init(name : String, id: String, theRate: String, quantity: String, sku: String, prdCateg:String, prodDescr: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.theRate = theRate
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.sku = sku
        self.prdCateg = prdCateg
        self.prodDescr = prodDescr

    }

    mutating func add(image: ProductImage) {
        images.append(image)
    }
}
```

And when I click on a button on an item of the collectionview, I load a tableviewcell which has all the details present in the collection view cell like name, rate etc.This is done like so...

```
 func SellBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

     let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPath(for: ((sender.superview?.superview) as! RecipeCollectionViewCell))

     self.photoThumbnail = self.arrayOfURLImages[(indexPath?.row)!]

     let myVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "productSellIdentifier") as! sellTableViewController

     let productObject = productData1[(indexPath?.row)!]
      if selectedItems == nil {

          selectedItems = [Product(name:productObject.name, id: productObject.id, theRate: productObject.theRate, quantity: productObject.quantity, sku: productObject.sku, prdCateg: productObject.prdCateg, prodDescr: productObject.prodDescr)]

     } else {
           selectedItems?.append(productObject)
     }

     myVC.arrProduct = selectedItems
     navigationController?.pushViewController(myVC, animated: true) 
}
```

But the issue is I'm not able to pass the image properly.

Also in the viewcontroller from where the tableviewcell is loaded, this is how I am assigning the data in the cellForRowAt…

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell: sellTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sellProductIdentifier") as! sellTableViewCell

   cell.prdImgView?.image = self.appDelegate.commonArrayForURLImages[indexPath.row]

   let product = arrProduct?[indexPath.row]
   cell.produvtNameLabel.text = product?.name
   cell.rateTextField.text = product?.theRate
   cell.remStockLabel.text = product?.quantity
   return cell
}
```

But the image displayed from the collectionview on each cell is not proper. In other words, the correct image from each indexpath is not shown...

Any help is appreciated...Thanks..:)

Comment: before calling the tableview, check the image passing in this line

  selectedItems = [Product(name:productObject.name, id: productObject.id, theRate: productObject.theRate, quantity: productObject.quantity, sku: productObject.sku, prdCateg: productObject.prdCateg, prodDescr: productObject.prodDescr)]

Comment: From this line you will get to know, where the actual issue lies

Comment: Hope it helps you to debug

Comment: did you check what url you get on self.appDelegate.commonArrayForURLImages[indexPath.row]

Comment: @cole The code snippet you mentioned was for dealing with data of struct Product. To get the images we need to process the struct ProductImage. But how that can be done I'm not sure...

Comment: check array of Url image or any place where you are passing images to tableview. You need to know which image are you passing ? 
And depending on that we can further debug the cause of it. If you still not able to do so. Let me know, I can post code snippet to give better clearity

Comment: I tried something like this in the sellBtnTapped method...selectedImgs = [ProductImage(id: imgObj.id, url: imgObj.url, isDefault: imgObj.isDefault)]'. This was done  below the 'selectedItems = [Product(name....'. In the cellForRowAt.. also, I'm getting all the values of struct like ProductImage(id: "960", url: http:/myUrl, isDefault: true)). But I think ultimately the image has to be passed to the array called arrProduct. But how that can b achieved that I'm not sure...